# What is a standard way to construct a turing machine for any function to compute

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I am new to turing machines, I am having problems with mapping a function to a turing maching that computes that particular function. for example:

1. f(x) = 2x + 3 n>= 0
2. MIN(x,y) leaves the smallest between x and y on the tape. e.g. x=2 y = 3 i.e. #aabaaa

I am not looking for a solution to the above but some kind of pattern i can use to solve these kind of particular problems quicker, in terms of transitions and what to have in mind before starting to solve.

Comment: Programming TMs is a pain. Why do you want to do that? That said, try formulating a "normal" program first, then translate to TM. (This question is very broad.)

Comment: How is this supposed to be read: f(x) = 2x + 3 n>= 0  ?

Comment: build primitives! subroutines! etc! lookup the concept of "assembly language", "machine codes", or "bytecodes" in java. the concept of language compilation is quite relevant. [more on this topic](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/code/turing-machine-compiler/) (ruby TM compiler, examples, source code, object code, etc)

Comment: babou i meant x>=0, I can see doing sub-routines is the way to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designing a Turing machine is pretty much like writing a program. You
have to choose a representation for the data and a corresponding code
(read * transitions*) to manipulate the data. Remember how we do
arithmetics (addition, multiplication, quotient, ...) by manipulating
in strange ways strings of symbols that represent numbers, whether in
unary or positional representation, or even with Roman numerals.

The difficulty is generally that the means for data representation are
pretty elementary: symbols on a tape. So you have to find ways to
encode everything into that. Also the programming instructions are
very simple. So you have to find a way (for complex machines) to
decompose the problem into parts, and to assemble the coresponding
machine parts. Pretty much what you do when you define functions and
subprograms in usual programming.

You can make your life easier by using different sets of states for
each subprogram. But basically people rarely design Turing machines,
except for specific proofs. Then the problem is often how to combine into one several simpler machines that have been separately designed. You can find that in textbooks.

It can be amusing to find elegant solutions for simple problems. Like
puzzles. You can add constraints. For example, you second question can
be solved in several ways. Some use more tape than others.

Exercise: do long multiplication of two binary numbers, then two
ternary numbers. Well, just think about it. Where would you store the
multiplication table?