# Why are syntax trees used in genetic programming?

Tags: algorithms, semantics, genetic-algorithms, syntax-trees, syntax

Reading a course on genetic programming, the first chapter describes the syntax tree as the basic representation of programs in genetic programming.

What are the reasons leading to the choice of a syntax tree in genetic programming? Are there any particular assets in using this representation?

Comment: Do you mean syntax trees produced by a parser, or rather what is usually called Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)?

Comment: I meant an AST.

Comment: Do you mean programs that implement genetic algorithms, or genetic algorithms that work on populations of programs? I don't understand the former question, and the latter probably has the boring answer "because it works better".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*In short*: **AST representations of programs are more easily analyzed,
manipulated, and transformed, while preserving and enforcing the existence of a
formally defined program meaning through the transformations.**

*I am asssuming that the reader knows already what is an [abstract syntax tree (AST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), and does not need to be shown examples.*

The question is an issue about abstract objects (semantics) and their
representations (syntax). We are usually interested in the semantics,
applying transformations to entities to change or combine their
meanings, their semantics, which can belong to all kinds of domains.
But semantics is elusive, mathematical abstraction, and all we can
actually manipulate to express our intent is syntax representations.

That is the basis of all programming, but is also to be found in
logic, proofs, and finally all of mathematics. That is what makes the
choice of representations and notations often so important. Good choice
of representation will lead to easier, possibly more perspicuous or
intuitive understanding of the problem and be better adapted at
expressing answers, and proofs, for given questions.

The point is well known to programmers, as they are taught that it is essential to
choose the right data structure in order to implement an algorithmic
solution to a given problem. The choice of data structure is the choice of
representation.  And I just made a similar answer to a [question on
constructing (programming?) Turing Machines](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42708/what-is-a-standard-way-to-construct-a-turing-machine-for-any-function-to-compute).

Note that there is a partially ambiguous use of the word syntax, which
can be any concrete representation of an abstraction, or can be
intended to mean only textual representation as strings (we are
getting close to Turing machines), possibly structured by some logical
system (a context-free (CF) grammar for example that specifies what
are the legitimate strings, the *well-formed-strings*.

In fact, the existing parsing-unparsing technology, especially for CF
grammars, makes it generally easy to switch between textual and an
associated tree representation, to the point that they are often not
distinguished much. Actually, mathematicians have been using tree
representation (formally defined as [Algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra)), long before that
technology existed, and this is what lead to using the representation of AST
in manipulating programs.

So what was so convenient about these tree (or AST) representations?

**The key points are:**

- **it is very convenient for associating precisely
  semantic meaning to syntactic constructs, in a compositional way, by means of a simple
  mathematical concept: the homomorphism;**
- **it provides and enforces a syntactic type system (statement, expression, ...) that preserve the existence of some meaning when the program representation is transformed in a way that preserves the syntactic typing constraints;**
- **it is easily manipulated to actually perform analysis and transformations;**
- **it is easy to decorate it with localized information to help or guide these analyses and transformations.**

First, if you take a string representation of a program, without
further structural information, there is no simple way to delimit
substrings that have naturally a meaning of their own (I am saying
*naturally*, because some people may always try to play at abstracting
syntactic context or indulge in syntactic (text oriented) continuation games - ignore this if
you do not get it).

The idea of a tree structure, with nodes labeled with operators, possibly
restricted by syntactic types (statement, expression, variable, ...)
is that they naturally decompose the syntactic structure into subparts
(the subtrees) that can have fairly naturally, and perspicuously with
respect to computational concepts, a semantic meaning of their own.

Then, if we associate a semantic function to each operator, we can get
the meaning of a tree representation by applying the semantic function
of the root operators to the semantic meaning of each of its subtrees.
If we also provide some semantics to leafs operators (which may be
defined as a mapping from syntactic representations to some semantic
domains possibly by other means, for example associating the integer
23 to the string "`23`"), we know how to define simply the semantics
of any well-formed tree, whether complete program or well-formed
program fragment. This is the basis of what is known as [denotational semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denotational_semantics).

In other word, the homomorphism thus defined gives a rather simple and
tractable way to associate meaning to well-formed program fragments, by composing the meanings of its well-formed sub-fragments (this is known as semantic compositionality).
Then, it becomes much easier to attempt defining semantically
meaningful transformations. And semantics, what the program (fragment)
does is what we really care about.

Furthemore, AST are fairly easy to manipulate by programs to express these transformations that somewhat respect the semantic structure (as they manipulate subtrees that are semantically meaningful), which initially justified their use in [program editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_editor), program manipulation systems, and programming environment.

Actually, the concept of AST in programming appeared with the language
Lisp (and its ability to manipulate Lisp programs syntactically) in
the very late fifties. But it developed mostly in the seventies ([Emily](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wjh/Emily.html), Cornell synthesizer, Mentor/Centaur), and further in the eighties, at the
same time as denotational semantics (which is based on the above
approach), and most likely under the influence of denotational
semantics. The early work ([LCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_for_Computable_Functions)) on automated proofs about computation may also have been influencial.

**From the point of view of genetic programming**, the use of AST both facilitates and enforces the
creation of syntactic structures that are more likely to have some
meaning. Manipulating unstructured string representations  would be
likely to result in being swamped with string representations to which
no meaning can be associated.

Another advantage of AST representations is that they are fairly easy
to decorate with additional information: precomputed semantic
properties, weights, or whatever is deemed useful for the intended
program transformation or manipulation, including genetically programed transformations.

### A detailed example

*This section has been added later to answer some comments.*

I will try to work out one example in some details to explain the
relation between manipulations on the AST and their semantics
conterpart.

We take a very simple example of crossover between two ASTs:
T1=`foo(exp1,exp2)` and T2=`bar(exp3, exp4)`. I keep it small for
readability. Actually, `exp1` to `exp4` are meant to be subtrees of
some AST, while you may also see what is around them as standing for
the rest of some AST (or some AST subtree) that is the context in
which they occur.

We suppose first that the language does not have typing (in the usual
sense of programing languages), and accept any value in any context
expecting a value, so that any expression can legitimately replace any
other.

Then given T1 and T2, it is legitimate to apply a crossover that swaps
`exp1` and `exp4`, thus producing T1'=`foo(exp4,exp2)` and
T2'=`bar(exp3, exp1)`. Note that the algorithm could also consider
only one of these two trees (I am incompetent regarding genetic
splicing strategies).

Now, let us see what can be said about semantics, without getting too
much into details.

Let $S$ be the semantic function, $V$ the domain of values, $M$ the
domain of environments that map identifiers to values. The semantics
$S$(`exp`) of an expression `exp` is a function $e: M\to V$ that takes
an environment $m$ as argument (so that we have values for
identifiers) and returns the value of the expression in that
environment.

Now, if the operators `foo` and `bar` are supposed to compute
respectively two functions $f$ and $b$ on their arguments,
the semantics of T1, for example, will be defined as

$S$(`foo(exp1,exp2)`)=$S$(`foo`)($S$(`exp1`),$S$(`exp2`))=$\lambda m.f(e_1(m),e_2(m))$

You notice that the semantic function is not necessarily easy to define in the
complex case of a programming language, since for `foo` we have here
$S$(`foo`)=$\lambda e, e', m\,.\, f(e(m), e'(m))$.

This complexity results from the choice of the Abstract Syntax, that
considers here `foo` and `bar` as AST operator nodes. Instead, the AST
could have a `call` operator that has several daughters, for example
as in `call(foo, exp1, exp2)`. Then the complexity of dealing with the
environment $m$ would be factorized in the semantics of `call`, while
the semantics of `foo` would simply be the function $f$.

Sorry for this complexity.

The whole point is that we can define the semantics of an AST subtree
such as `exp1` independently of any context, but as a
function $e_1$. Whatever information it needs from the context to be
evaluated is summarized in the arguments (here the environment $m$)
that are passed to its semantics. And this information is in turn
passed to the semantic functions associated to subexpressions.

So now we know that a subtree of AST can have a well defined
semantics, independently of its context.

But what about the context? Does it have a well defined semantics when
a subtree is missing. The nice point is that it does.

If you consider the context `foo(??,exp2)`, what can its semantics be.
The natural answer is that it is whatever semantics it would have if
you provided the missing part. In other words, it is a functional
semantics that takes as argument the semantics of the missing part.
This is very similar to the semantics of the complete expression
$S$(`foo(exp1,exp2)`) that we defined above, except that the missing
`exp1` must be accounted for with an argument $e$ standing for the
semantics of whatever expression could replace `exp1`.

We had $S$(`foo(exp1,exp2)`)=$\lambda m.f(e_1(m),e_2(m))$

So, without going into further details, you have

$S$(`foo(??,exp2)`)=$\lambda e.\lambda m.f(e(m),e_2(m))$

Then, given that $S$(`exp1`)=$e_1: M\to V$,
we have
$S$(`foo(exp1,exp2)`)= $S$(`foo(??,exp2)`)($S$(`exp1`))

which is precisely what we would like: syntactic abstraction directly
translate into semantic abstraction.

Then we also have, of course:

$S$(`foo(exp4,exp2)`)= $S$(`foo(??,exp2)`)($S$(`exp4`))

In other words, both AST subtrees and AST contexts (of subtree) have
well defined semantics, that do not change, and they compose to give
the semantics of the whole AST tree when a subtree is placed in a
permitted context.

But of course: $S$(`foo(exp1,exp2)`) $\neq$ $S$(`foo(exp4,exp2)`)

I hope this explains how things work. Using well-formed AST will
ensure that you are actually manipulating semantic fragments that
compose meaningfully.

Actually, things may be a bit more complicated, because you want to
include in the process what is usually called static semantics,
i.e. constraints on the AST that are usually checked at compile time.
The best known examples are type constraints for statically typed
languages, or declaration of identifiers when that is required.  Thus
you may want to decorate ASTs with this statically computable
information, and use splicing techniques that will incrementally
preserve the information and check the required constraints on the AST, so that you produce only programs that at least compile.

Then as a last comment, I would like to remarks that linear genetic
programming seems to be doing pretty much the same, but restricts
splicing to sequences of statements, so that there is always some
executable semantics preserved. But I am not specialist of that.

Comment: From what you just said, are ASTs in genetic programming (or sub trees) supposed to be meaningly equivalent? Semantic is described by syntax to a certain point, but no homomorphism operation could be performed if ASTs differ by their level of semantics (or abstraction) during crossovers for example.

For example, the operation 3 + 3 + 3 is globally equivalent to 3 * 3 but can we truly say that the '+' operator is semantically equivalent to the '*' operator because it gives us the same result?

Comment: @Chirac In simple crossover, the semantics of the subparts that are being
swapped stays unchanged. But the semantics of the individual trees
affected by the crossover is usually changed. What is always
preserved, however, is the existence of some well defined semantics
for each. The role of homomorphism is to define the semantics of
whatever AST tree or subtree you are considering. It does not
participate in the genetic AST transformations. However, it can also
be used to associate an unchanging meaning to the 2 tree contexts
where the cross-over takes place.

Comment: @Chirac For example, if you have the AST for `foo(exp1,exp2)` and `bar(exp3,
exp4)`. You swap `exp1` and `exp4` in a crossover. The semantics of
`exp1`, `exp2`, `exp3`, and `exp4` are preserved, and so is the
semantic of `foo(??,exp2)` and `bar(exp3,??)` which is actually a
functional semantics. But the semantics of the two complete trees has
changed.  Am I answering your question?

Comment: @Chirac What we can say, for example is that `x+x+x` is equivalent to `3*x`
and to `x*3`. Actually, it should be said with `x` as a syntactic
metavariable that could be any AST expression (up to type - I have to skip
details). Such equivalences were used at some point to perform
semantics preserving program transformations. Applicability of
such tranformations was driven by matching techniques, on trees, on
terms of equational algebras, or on lambda terms. I guess the same
techniques could be used for more complex mutations or crossovers in genetic
programming, no longer semantics preserving.

Comment: From your second comment, why would the semantics of the two complete trees change if their functional semantic is preserved?

Comment: @Chirac I added a complete example, unfortunately long and a bit technical, to explain the situation in denotational semantics terms. I hope this aswers your question.

Comment: According to some papers I have read CSTs are actually used to generate populations? So, it's a little confusing for me when I read in your answer that ASTs are used

Comment: @Marin Accurate answer would probably require a look at the papers. The
OP was asking about ST, and I naturally assumed that he implied AST
because I have no experience of a situation where CST would be
better. CST are just a technological artefact due to the popular use
of constrained parsing technique (such as LR. LL, ...)  that force an
inadequate structure on the syntax for allegedly more effective
parsability. AST is the more natural and perspicuous representation,
but (OTTOMH) CST can be used as well, though it is structured for
reasons irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Marin Thinking longer about your question, CST can indeed be used to define
semantics, in the same way as AST. But this may have to be done in
very contrived ways, so that the semantic function may be very
unatural, and much more complex. Though manipulating syntactic
elements (genes), genetics programming really deals with the meanings
of these elements. It should be more effective when they are
simpler meanings. The literature should have something on this. Else,
it could be an interesting topic for experimental research.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax trees provide an abstract representation of a program with a certain kind of *type* information at each vertex. This allows, when attempting to evolve a program, the swapping/changing of subtrees as long as the root vertex of the subtrees have the same type. As long as the program was valid, (and the subtrees are also valid), the result will still be a valid program.

As a somewhat trivial example if your programming language has a rule for addition expressions along the lines of $\langle plus \rangle ::= \langle expression_{1}\rangle + \langle expression_{2} \rangle$, then anything that is an $expression$ (i.e. that satisfies the typing rules for $expression$) can be put in place for $\langle expression_{1}\rangle$ or $\langle expression_{2} \rangle$. So if you're trying to implement a crossover operator for example, you know the places where you can swap subtrees and still get something that makes at least a basic level of sense.

This is also why syntax trees are a very important tool in compilation - they have the same utility as representations of the flat text of the program.

Note that tree representations aren't the only way, see for example [linear genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_genetic_programming).

Comment: Thank you for this. I've always seen syntax trees as hierarchical tools to order data and links between data. For example the number 3 and 5 being dependent on the + operator. With your answer, if I understand correctly, it also provides a structure, an entity for my data to be changed dynamically with crossovers etc.. Okay! Thanks again!

Comment: I am wondering whether linear genetic programming (LGP) should not be
seen as a degenerate form of AST based genetic programming. Since the
main advantage of AST is to enforce existence of meaning through
syntactic types. The point is that LGP, as I understand, is only
editing statement sequences, hence preserving a trivial form of
syntactic typing.

Comment: To emphasise this: normal "genetic" operations on strings will produce invalid texts (in the sense that the resulting program is not syntactically and semantically valid) with high probability, thus the algorithm will be very, very inefficient. (Decorated) ASTs can be used to define more meaningful operations that maintain validity (with high probability).